# XAML Designer and VS 2010 hanging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xaml

VS 2010 hangs when using the XAML designer. I don't think I have memory issues as the system has 4 gigs of RAM. I know that there were issues with VS 2008 SP1 that was fixed a patch.

They don't seem to have one for VS 2010. Anyone else has this issue?

Is there a workaround in using the designer?

Anyone? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround** is a open `.xaml` file in `notepad.exe`

Comment: +1, totally agree. I've fixed the issue by associating the XAML extension in Visual Studio with the simple XML editor. Works like charm. You even get syntax highlighting :-)

Comment: Well, I'd like to use the designer as it makes it easier to move the activities around.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me :

Right click on the file you want to open in Solution explorer
- Select Open with...
- Select "Source Code (Text) Editor
- Click "Set as Default"
- Click OK